# query and variable in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following query in google spreadsheet (!classement H6)

```
=QUERY(classement!A2:C367;"SELECT COUNT(B) WHERE  B='worry' AND C=2")
```

This query works and I have good result

If I want to reference a cell with the same value I12=2 my result is empty

```
=QUERY(classement!B2:D367;"SELECT COUNT(B) WHERE B='worry' AND C= '"&classement!I12 &"'")
```

here is my google spreadsheet [exemple](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ofhVeYT7m2u9MTIP01iBCRqt6YRMjVaFcyBcOMf7b1s/edit?usp=sharing)

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks

Noliverte

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the ticks (`'`) as in your first the number is not with ticks, but in the second it is, this is because you are looking for a number value

`=QUERY(classement!B2:D367;"SELECT COUNT(B) WHERE B='worry' AND C= "&classement!I12 &"")`

Comment: you're welcome, don't forget to leave the answer accepted if it solved your problem